# How to innest 2 grids properly in a same view with Gijgo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I have a problem with gijco grid in this case.

I have 2 grids in a same View (ASP.NET MVC).

If I have a pager in the first grid and not in second, the second grid doesn't load tha data... if I uncomment the pager on second grid (with the same condition) the data are loaded properly (see code).

**Source**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        datasourceiniziale = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PSA));
        dsIstruttori = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Istruttori));
        $("#hdatasource").val(JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PSA))));
        grid = $("#gridPSA").grid({
            pager: { enable: true, limit: 10, sizes: [10, 20, 50, 100] },
            dataSource:  datasourceiniziale,
            selectionMethod: 'checkbox',
            selectionType: 'multiple',
            detailTemplate: '<div class="panel-footer"><div class="alert alert-warning small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br /><b>idPSAAzienda:</b>{idPSAAzienda}<br /><b>idToken:</b>{idToken}<br /><b>Compilatore;</b>{Compilatore}<br /><ul><li><b>CompilatoreContatti:</b>{CompilatoreContatti}</li></div></div>',
            dataKey: "Id",
            uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
            columns:
            [
                { field: "Id", sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "idPSAAzienda", sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "idToken", sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "Compilatore",  sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "CompilatoreContatti",  sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "RagioneSociale", sortable: false, title: "Ragione Sociale"  },
                { field: "Comune", sortable: false, title: "Comune"   }
                //,
                //{ width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-pencil", tooltip: "Modifica", events: { "click": Edit } },
                //{ width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-remove", tooltip: "Elimina", events: { "click": Delete } }
            ]
        });

        gridIstruttori = $("#gridIstruttori").grid({
            dataSource:  dsIstruttori, 
            //pager: { enable: false, limit: 10, sizes: [10, 20, 50, 100] },
            selectionMethod: 'checkbox',
            selectionType: 'multiple',
            detailTemplate: '<div class="panel-footer"><div class="alert alert-warning small"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span><br /><b>IdUtente:</b>{IdUtente}<br /><b>UserName:</b>{UserName}<br /></div></div>',
            dataKey: "Id",
            uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
            columns:
            [
                { field: "IdUtente", sortable: false, hidden: true },
                { field: "Cognome",  sortable: false},
                { field: "Nome",  sortable: false },
                { field: "UserName", sortable: false, title: "Username", hidden: true    }
            ]
        });

    });
```

Where is the error? 
Exist a workaround for this situation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in version 0.6.
This is an example with workaround for this issue.

```
 <table id="grid1"></table>
 <table id="grid2"></table>
 <script>
     var data1 = [
         { 'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Hristo Stoichkov', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Plovdiv, Bulgaria' },
         { 'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Ronaldo Luis Nazario de Lima', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil' },
         { 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'David Platt', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Chadderton, Lancashire, England' }
     ];
     var data2 = [
         { 'ID': 1, 'Name': 'Hristo Stoichkov', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Plovdiv, Bulgaria' },
         { 'ID': 2, 'Name': 'Ronaldo Luis Nazario de Lima', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Rio de Janeiro, Brazil' },
         { 'ID': 3, 'Name': 'David Platt', 'PlaceOfBirth': 'Chadderton, Lancashire, England' }
     ];
     $('#grid1').grid({
         dataSource: data1,
         uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
         columns: [ { field: 'ID' }, { field: 'Name' }, { field: 'PlaceOfBirth' } ],
         pager: { limit: 2, sizes: [2, 5, 10, 20] }
     });
     gj.grid.methods.getRecordsForRendering = function ($grid) {
        return $grid.data('records');
     };
     $('#grid2').grid({
         dataSource: data2,
         uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
         columns: [ { field: 'ID' }, { field: 'Name' }, { field: 'PlaceOfBirth' } ]
     });
 </script>
```

This is already fixed in version 1.0 and above I would recommend you to upgrade to new version from http://gijgo.com